# Magento 2 ECE : how to access root privileges

Tags: magento2-enterprise

I just need to edit some .cnf file in cloud server. 
but in documentation they are write : you can access this file As a user with root privileges
how can i use root privileges in server.

any idea please share

Answer (score 1):

Magento Enterprise Cloud edition does not provide root access to their server.

However, you can send a support request if you want to change some restricted file.

To do so, log in to **`magento.cloud`** website and click on the **`Support Tickets`** link.

Click on **`Create Ticket`** button to submit a new ticket.